# How to extract and analyse data inside a dict in a loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data like this,they are in one file.

```
c:\windows\system32\aa.exe:
    Verified:   Unsigned
    File date:  ?? 02:14 2008/12/22
    Publisher:  n/a

c:\windows\system32\bb.dll:
    Verified:   Unsigned
    Link date:  ?? 07:14 2003/3/27
    Publisher:  Microsoft Corporation
```

I had written a code to turn  into dict.
The output will be like this.

```
path : c:\windows\system32\aa.exe
Verified:   Unsigned
... ...
```

But I do not know how to make a loop to extract right part and analysis it.

I want put  every "path data" and the following data into a dict.

Could anyone  give me some advice?Thx!

Below is my code.

```
with open(fileee, encoding = "UTF-8") as r:
  stdout = r.read()
  for line in stdout.splitlines():
    if not ':\\' in line:
      key, sep, value = line.partition(':')
    else:
      key = 'path'
      sep = ':'
      value = str(line)[:-1]

    if sep == ':':
        dic = getinfo()
```

Comment: You are overwriting the keys in the dictionary for each document, you want a dictionary for file o just one with all the data?

Comment: I want it can be like this.{path:...,verified:...}{path:...,verified:...}.

Comment: Yes, I have a overwriting problem. That what I want to figure out. I don't know what to do when meet second "path data".

Comment: Well...I figure out. Because all data has same row. When readlines function read fixed rows, I return the dict.Thank you for your help.